# Capillary bridge force function given volume and distance

Tags: pressure, water, fluid-statics, capillary-action, adhesion

Given two surfaces and a fluidic [glue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_bridges#/media/File:Concave_capullary_bridge.jpg) with sufficient adhesion, what is the force provided by the [capillary bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_bridges) provided the cohesive properties of the glue, volume, and distance between the surfaces?

So, for water, there should exist a function f such that f(Volume, distance) is the force of attraction between two parallel flat surfaces which water is attracted to more than itself.

I can ignore gravity and elasticity of the surfaces and perhaps an assumption on the surrounding air pressure.